# Trouble with wxWidgets install

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have been trying to install wxWidgets on Visual Studio 2010 but I keep getting the same error. It would be great if some one could tell me what it means and how I can fix my problem.

This is the error message I keep getting

> Error 1 error MSB3073: The command "xcopy ....\include\wx\msw\setup.h ....\lib\vc_dll\mswu\wx\ /Y
>   :VCEnd" exited with code 4. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 103 6 richtext

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed wxWidgets-2.8.10 in C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-2.8.10

( If you have installed a different version, adjust accordingly. )

Check that the file C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-2.8.10\include\wx\msw\setup.h exists.

Check that the folder C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-2.8.10\lib\vc_dll\mswu\wx exists and you have write permission to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what package of wxWidgets you installed, you may need to copy include/wx/msw/setup0.h to include/wx/msw/setup.h (making any config changes you need while you're at it, but try getting default settings working first before changing stuff). Usually only the zip and installer packages do this for you automatically as it's assumed that if you use other packages, you aren't installing it on Windows.

You definitely have to do this if you checked out the source directly from SVN.

One last note, considering you are using VC10, you may run into issues building wxWidgets 2.8 as VC10 was not supported with that version. If you do run into problems you can't solve, give wxWidgets 2.9+ (version 2.9.2 is due to be released sometime in the next month here).